# Graphing Libraries for WPF in the .NET Framework?

Tags: software-development, .net, graphs, wpf

I am currently building an application using WPF in the .NET framework. The application will involve graphing data. Are there any good open-source graphing libraries or packages out there I can use for my application? When I say graph, I mean something that looks like:

[image]

Comment: What specific graph types (e.g. pie charts) do you need? Anything concerning the amount of data they must be capable to process? Output file types?

Comment: Nah nothing like that yet, don't have a set of requirements in front of me yet. Just brainstorming for now.

Comment: Well, this is no brainstorming site :) To give recommendations, we need specific requirements. Please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Without specific requirements, questions tend to get closed pretty soon as either "too broad" or "unclear what you're asking". You should have a rough idea on the amount of data already. So make this one specific for that amount, decide on "at least <chart types>", and decide on graphic formats (jpg/png or rather vector formats like svg). If needed, ask a new Q later.

Answer (score 1):

***Disclosure**, I work for SciChart*

SciChart's [WPF Chart](http://scichart.com/wpf-chart-features/) is an option to consider

SciChart is mostly focussed on enterprise applications built in WPF and is designed to be a high performance option for applications that require big-data and complex interactions.

[image: WPF Chart Library]

It's not free (commercial software), however a [free version](http://scichart.com/educational-discount-programme/) is available for educational use. Plans are in the works for free community versions for non-profits as well

Answer (score 0):

[Essential Chart for WPF](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/sfchart) is an option to consider.

[image: Line chart drag drop]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue), but not open source.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: That seems like an option.

Comment: Although it's free, it's not open-source.